# React showing component before going through the render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-starter-kit

My react component is being showed (and it is complete functional) before going through the `render()` method.

The project is using the `react-starter-kit`, and a similar route code can be accessed [here](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/routes/home/index.js).

[image: Router code]

In the picture above I'm calling a bunch of actions and then returning the target component (***Question***).

Part of the component code is in the following image:

[image: Component code]

The problem is that the component is available and completely functional before both `console.log` be called:

[image: Console debugging]

In this case the component is available since the fist action call, but the `logs` are shown after everything. I want to add a loader since the beginning. Anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: looking at the logs, a lot of actions are being called. could you share details of atleast one action where its called, say "SET_QUIZ_TYPE"

Comment: Even being lots of actions, all of these are pretty straighforward state-change actions. There is no collateral effect on changing routes or loading different components.

Comment: I think you should be using async actions http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably the component being rendered on the server-side.

Since it will set all flags/states to "loaded" because it was rendered it might cause conflicts with the frontend scritps.

To avoid such conflicts you can check if your code is running on frontend or backend using:

```
const isBack = typeof window === 'undefined';
```

If there is no DOM available then it is on the server.

Comment: Amazing! It was exactly that. Thank you